# PHP: Image is not displaying from SQL datdabase

Tags: php, html

I have checked out other questions of same topic on this site and tried to find the solution but unsuccessful. Images are stored in database and loaded in folder successfully but are not displayed
**Here is my code:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="image_description" placeholder="Enter name" required>
            <input type="file" name="myfile">
            <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $image_description = $_POST['image_description'];
    $name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

    $upload=move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploaded/" . $name);

    $query= "INSERT INTO image(image_description,image_name,image_type,image_size) VALUES ('$image_description','$name','$type','$size')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query) && $upload) {
        echo "successfully uploaded";
    }
    else
       die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM image");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{?> 
        <img style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" src="<?php echo 'uploaded/' .$row['image_name'] ?>"> 
<?php
    echo $row['image_description'] . "<br>";
}?>
```

**Images are displayed as in picture**

[image: Images are displayed as in picture]

**This is database table**

[image: This is database table]

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection... You shouldn't use unsanitised PHP variables in a query. Have you checked what the value of `$row['image_name']` is in your PHP code? Are they correct? Do those files exist?

Comment: I will work for it later(injection). As i told it is stored is database successfully.

Comment: Yes it may be stored in your database successfully - but is the `PHP` code actually retrieving that data? When you output the `img` tag, what is the `src` attribute? Is it what you're expecting?

Comment: What if you try to directly open the URL of such an image (right click, open image in new tab, or something along those lines)...?

Comment: src attribute contains folder and file name

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `HTML` output for us to see please?

Comment: Not displaying in new tab

Comment: What *is* the URL of the file (in the new tab)? What ***should*** it be?

Comment: Sample of `HTML` output mean here

Comment: I have posted all the code

Comment: `http://localhost/image.php/uploaded/timeTable.jpg` @deceze

Comment: Is there a folder "index.php/uploaded/" on your disk? ... Yeah, didn't think so.

Comment: folder name is `uploaded`

Comment: You guys should start a chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL of your page is `index.php/`; notice the trailing slash.
A *relative URL* (e.g. `src="uploaded/.."`) will resolve to `index.php/uploaded/..`.
That folder obviously does not exist on your disk.

1. Use root-relative URLs: `src="/uploaded/.."`
2. ***or*** use relative URLs but go to the right folder: `src="../uploaded/.."`
3. ***or*** fix your weird URL and make it `index.php`, from which even relative URLs will resolve correctly.

Comment: I have tried it `<img style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" src="<?php echo "/uploaded/" .$row['image_name'] ?>">`. It worked successfully